# ffmpeg extension isn't installing

Tags: windows-7, ffmpeg, 64-bit, wamp

I'm using wamp server v2.2 x64 and php version 5.3.13. I'm trying to install ffmpeg during two days. I fallowed this steps:

- Download dll files for x64 (I'm using windows7 x64)
- copied ffmpeg.dll to bin\php\php5.3.13\ext
- copied rest of dll files to system32
- enable ffmpeg extension from wamp server.

and I checked phpinfo() but it's not working. 
by the way is there any way to take a frame from video for poster image ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get `php_ffmpeg` working you are going to have to find someone that has recompiled it with the VC9 compiler for 64bit and in a thread safe way.

You may find this difficult, I cannot find anything out there yet having just googled around for it.

You would find it easier if you un-install WAMP 64bit and install the WAMP 32bit. There is a `php_ffmpeg.dll` available in that environment

> PS There is no issue with running 32bit WAMP on a 64bit OS.